# Вёрстка. Как можно минимизировать/улучшить адаптив?

Tags: html, адаптивная-верстка

я начинающий! Сверстал первый макет, хотел спросить про качество адаптивного дизайна, что сделано не правильно, а что правильно, может что-то можно улучшить/переделать.... В сети каких-то особых требований к адаптиву не нашёл(кто-то делает под самые популярные размеры устройства - 1440px 320px как пример, кто-то просто аккуратно сворачивает блоки чтобы они не наезжали друг на друга). Хотелось бы сложить в голове примерную картину "как надо", проанализировав мнение более опытных коллег... Если есть замечания по другим частям работы, укажите пожалуйста, постараюсь исправить

[Ссылка на вёрстку](http://Vlad-Vasinev.github.io)

Заранее спасибо всем откликнувшимся!

Comment: вёрстку сюда надо - у меня к примеру этот сайт не открывается

Comment: извините, не понял, куда именно надо вёрстку?

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: https://vlad-vasinev.github.io/

Comment: Странно было увидеть стандартный отступ у body в 8px.